# How to show clicks all the time

Tags: javascript

I have this code, it counts the clicks on the button.
But it only shows the clicks after you click on the button.

I need to show the clicks al the time, even when you don't click the button.

```
<html>
   <head>
 <script>
function clickCounter() {
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.clickcount) {
        localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
    } else {
        localStorage.clickcount = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + localStorage.clickcount + " time(s).";
} else {
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
}
}
 </script>
</head>
  <body>
  <p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
  <div id="clicks"></div>

 </body>
```

I hope someone can help me out here.

Comment: So attach the function (clickCounter) to the body's onclick event instead of button's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to invoke a method at `DOMContentLoaded` event

```
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  var clickCount = localStorage.clickcount || 0;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + clickCount + " time(s).";
});
```

Just add this code in your `script` tag

Comment: And where do i have to place this in my script? I'am very new with this

Comment: Like I have mentioned in my answer - Put this code in the script tag that you already have.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var hasLocalStorage = false;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var element = document.getElementById("clicks");

  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    var clicks = localStorage.clickcount || 0;
    hasLocalStorage = true;
    updateMessage(element, clicks);
  }

  document.getElementById('clicker').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var clicks;

    if (hasLocalStorage && localStorage.clickcount) {
      clicks = Number(localStorage.clickcount) + 1;
    }

    updateMessage(element, clicks);
  });
});



function updateMessage(element, clicks) {
  if (!element) {
    return;
  }

  var message = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";

  if (clicks >= 0) {
    message = "You have clicked the button " + clicks + " time(s).";
    localStorage.clickcount = clicks;
  }

  element.innerHTML = message;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button id="clicker" type="button">Click me!</button>
</p>
<div id="clicks"></div>
```